# C++ (Particle Photon) Threading with changing variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, arduino

**Note:** The code is designed to run on a Particle Photon. Please keep this in mind while reading my question.

I want to make a led blink based on a variable called `blink_type` this variable will be changed dynamically in a later stage when I implement the API call to fetch the status of something else. I'm currently simulating this behaviour in the `loop()` function (also tried a thread but that also didn't work).

The blinking works fine until the variable changes from 0 to 1, after that it never blinks again until I do a reset.

Below you will find my code:

```
// This #include statement was automatically added by the Particle IDE.
#include <httpsclient-particle.h>

// Base variables.
int led = D0;
int buzzer = D1;
// Defining blink types. 0 is normal, 1 is breathe.
int blink_type = 0;

// Set the threads
Thread *normalBlinkThread;
Thread *ledBreatherThread;

void setup() {
  // Setup the outputs.    
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);

  // Create the required threads.
  normalBlinkThread = new Thread("rest_status_light", normalBlink);
  ledBreatherThread = new Thread("rest_status_light", hearthBeatBlink);

}

os_thread_return_t normalBlink(void*) {
    // Start never ending loop
    for(;;) {
        if(blink_type == 0) {
            // Blink led
            digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
            delay(3000);
            digitalWrite(led, LOW);
            delay(3000);   
        }
    }
}

os_thread_return_t hearthBeatBlink(void*) {
    // Start never ending loop
    for(;;) {
        if(blink_type == 1) {
            // Blink led
            digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
            delay(3000); 
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    delay(10000);
    switch (blink_type) {
        case 0:
            blink_type = 1;
            break;

        case 1:
            blink_type = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

To not get confused, the "buzzer" output (D1) is currently also wired to an LED.

If there would be a better approach to blink a led in two different ways based on a dynamic variable I'm happy to adopt to this sollution!

Comment: Elephant in the room: `loop` does not loop.

Comment: @user4581301 Like said in the question, I also tested it with an infinite `for` loop in a separate `thread` same result.

Comment: Regardless, it does not loop. This makes it very hard to tell if another change to the code actually fixed the problem.When faced with a mystery bug, prefer code that should work over code you know can't.

Comment: normalBlink() and hearthBeatBlink() have delays only when (blink_type == 1). When blink_type becomes 0 there are no delays in the for loops and one of them, the first which evaluates the variable change, happily spins for eternity, as cmaster said. Try to add a small delay in the case blink_type is 0.

Comment: @SimoneCifani you are indeed correct. Adding a small delay in the loop of 100ms solved the issue. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normalBlink() and hearthBeatBlink() have delays only when (blink_type == 1). When blink_type becomes 0 there are no delays in the for loops and one of them, the first which evaluates the variable change, happily spins for eternity. Try to add a small delay in the case blink_type is 0. Hope this helps!